# HTML, Bootstrap and CSS 3

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have my footer at the bottom of the page. If the page is long enough, I want to have to scroll to the footer. If the page is too short, I still want my footer at the very bottom of the viewport. I don't mind the empty space.

How can I achieve this as painlessly as possible?

I tried `navbar-static` and `nav-bar fixed` and they both don't do what I am looking for. Is filling the space with a spacer *div* or something the only way or is there a more elegant way using **CSS3** or some **javascript**?

Open to any and all ideas/suggestions.

This is the HTML I have. Nothing special coz I tried `position: absolute;bottom:0px;` and that put the footer at the bottom of shorter pages but in longer pages the bottom hangs in the mid of the page overlapping content.

This code puts the footer at the bottom of the page but in pages which are shorter than the window/viewport the footer sort-of hangs in the middle (at the end of the content).

```
.body
{
height: 100%;
}    
.bottomMenu 
    { 
        background-color: @backgroundColor;
        border-top: solid 1px (@backgroundColor - #292929);
    }
```

Comment: Show your html, css, and also read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you actually tried anything yet?  If so please edit your question to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering this css:

```
.stickToBottom {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

You need to detect if vertical scroll is present using javascript :

```
function isVerticalScrollPresent() {
   return document.documentElement.scrollHeight !== document.documentElement.clientHeight;
}
```

Then add "stickToBottom" class to the footer if this function returns false :

```
var footer = document.querySelector('footer');
if (!isVerticalScrollPresent()) {
    footer.className += " stickToBottom";
}
```

You can ignore css code and set footer style with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [example](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/) from the official Bootstrap documentation.

And here is the code:

HTML

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the page is very long. Also, places footer on top of content.

Answer (score -1):

Check this JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/LeoAref/9v0r7h9y/

HTML

```
<footer>Footer Content</footer>
```

CSS

```
html {
   height: 100%;
}

body {
   min-height: 100%;
   padding-bottom: 25px;
}

footer {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   background: red;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 7px 0;
   text-align: center;
}
```

You may need to use `box-sizing: border-box;` if you won't use bootstrap

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but your code doesn't do what he asks for, it does something different.